# Apply Kolmogorov's $0-1$-law.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ an i.i.d. sequence of random variables. Assume that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} |\sum_{i=1}^n X_i|/\sqrt{n \log \log n} < \infty$ almost surely.

My book claims that by Kolmogorov's $0-1$-law, there is a positive constant $K $ such that

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i|}{\sqrt{n \log\log n}} \leq K < \infty \quad a.s.$$

I'm not sure how to apply this $0-1$ law here.

Put $$Z := \limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i|}{\sqrt{n \log\log n}}$$

and define the tail-sigma algebra$$\mathcal{T}:= \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \sigma\{X_m, X_{m+1}, \dots\}$$

I want that $Z$ is $\mathcal{T}$-measurable (or at least that the events $\{Z \leq K\}$ are in the tail-sigma-algebra, but why is this the case?

Comment: What is your book, and where in it does it claim this?

Comment: It's not really a book, but written notes (not in English) so I can't really reference it.

Comment: This looks like the law of the iterated logarithm, but with a couple of differences. As far as $Z$ being $\mathcal T$-measurable, this follows from the value of $Z$ being independent of the value of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ for any finite $n$. I believe, anyway.

Comment: Ha yes, this occurs in the proof of the converse of the law of the iterated logarithm I'm reading. Without the absolute value sign, you can see that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i/\sqrt{n \log \log n} = (\sum_{i=1}^m X_i+\sum_{m+1}^n X_i)/\sqrt{n \log \log n}$ for $n \geq m \geq 1$ and then by taking limsups of both sides indeed the value does not depend on the first $m-1$ terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have defined $Z := \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i|}{\sqrt{n \log \log n}}$. For any $K$, the event $\{Z \le K\}$ lies in $\mathcal{T}$ because $Z$ does not depend on any finite subset of the $X_i$.

---

Explicitly, let us show $\{Z \le K\} \in \sigma\{X_m, X_{m+1}, \ldots\}$.

Note that for $n > m$,
$$
\frac{|\sum_{i=m}^n X_i|}{\sqrt{n \log \log n}}
- \frac{|\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} X_i|}{\sqrt{n \log \log n}}
\le \frac{|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i|}{\sqrt{n \log \log n}}
\le \frac{|\sum_{i=m}^n X_i|}{\sqrt{n \log \log n}}
+ \frac{|\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} X_i|}{\sqrt{n \log \log n}}$$
Since $\frac{|\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} X_i|}{\sqrt{n \log \log n}} \to 0$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$,
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i|}{\sqrt{n \log \log n}}
= \limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{|\sum_{i=m}^n X_i|}{\sqrt{n \log \log n}}$$
almost surely.

Comment: @user661541 I've attempted an explanation, but I may be wrong... feel free to correct me if I've made mistakes.

Comment: I think it's correct! It follows the same idea I had in a comment above, but this is even better. Thank you!

Comment: @angryavian I see that we have proved that $\{Z\leqslant K\}$ is a tail event, but have we actually shown that $\mathbb P(Z\leqslant K)=1$? Does the value $K$ depend on the distribution of the $X_1$?

Comment: @Math1000 What we have shown is that for each value of $K$, $P(Z \le K)$ is either zero or one. If this probability is zero for all $K$, then this violates the assumption "$Z < \infty$ a.s." stated at the beginning of the question. So there exists some $K$ such that $P(Z \le K) = 1$, which is exactly what the question is asking to show. (And yes, for different distributions of $X_1$, this constant will differ.)

Comment: I see, clever argument. +1

Comment: More precisely, note that $1=P(Z < \infty)=\lim_{K\to \infty} P(Z \leq K)$ by continuity of measure and thus there is $K$ s.t. $P(Z \leq K) \geq 1/2$. Thus by 0-1 law this must be 1.